# Method mocked with NSabstitute returns '0' instead of HttpStatusCode.OK

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute

Why do I get int value **'0'** after mocking my service and specifying return value as **HttpStatusCode.OK**?

1. First I mock my service :

> ```
>   private readonly IService service= Substitute.For<IService>();
> ```

2. Then in the test :

   ```
   var statusCode = service.DoSomethingAndReturnHttpStatusCode(xmlDocument).Returns(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   ```
3. In the end return value is statusCode = 0

What I would expect is : **OK**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right answer would be

> Returns() will only apply to **given combination of arguments**, so other
> calls to this method will return a default value instead.

Given argument will be compared to configured one. In your case configured instance of `xmlDocument` is different than instance passed to the method in the class under the test.

You have two options:
Ignore given argument - but lose some test coverage

```
var result = 
   service.DoSomething(null).ReturnForAnyArgs(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Verify given argument before returning expected value

```
var result = service
    .DoSomething(Arg.Is<XmlDocument>(doc => doc != null))
    .Returns(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

Comment: The latter is the right way and should be the accepted answer